# Permutation of words in a sentence

Tags: c, array

There is a problem which discusses in how many ways can the words in a sentence be permuted . I wrote a code as follows which works for the sentences (I think so) . It would be helpful if anyone can assure me if it's actually correct or not . Besides , any suggestion regarding the shortening of code or easing the logic is appreciated . Thanks...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int factorial(int x)
{
    if(x<=0) return 1;
    else return x*factorial(x-1);
};

int main(void)
{
    int T;//number of test cases
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--){
    char str[20];
    scanf(" %[^\n]",str);
    int i,j,k,m,count=0,l,p=1,n;
    l=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(str[i]==' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
    m=count+1;
    char arr[m][50];
    int check[m],func[m];
    for(i=0,k=0,j=0;j<=l;j++){
        if(str[j]==' '||j==l){
            check[i]=0;func[i]=1;
            arr[i][k]='\0';
            i++;
            k=0;
        }
        else{
            arr[i][k]=str[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(j=i+1;j<m;j++){
    if(check[i]==0&&strcmp(arr[i],arr[j])==0){
        check[j]++;
        func[i]++;
    }
  }
}
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    p*=factorial(func[i]);
}
n=factorial(m)/p;
printf("%d/%d\n",1,n);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
       2

       I eat rice

       no game no life
```

**Output:**

```
       1/6

       1/12
```

**N.B.:** The permutation within a word is to be ignored .

Comment: Note, you should have verified correctness before posting, as that's a requirement here. If you can verify that it's working as expected, we can review what you have. And whats the output that you're expecting?

Answer (score 3):

Some comments on the style of your code.

1. **Formatting**. Your code is hard to read because there are no spaces.
   Also the formatting seems to be off. It might be easier to read like this:

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       int T;//number of test cases
       scanf("%d", &T);
       while (T--) {

           char str[20];
           scanf(" %[^\n]", str);

           int i, j, k, m, count = 0, l, p = 1, n;
           l = strlen(str);

           for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
               if (str[i] == ' ') {
                   count++;
               }
           }

           m = count + 1;
           char arr[m][50];
           int check[m], func[m];

           for (i = 0, k = 0, j = 0; j <= l; j++) {
               if (str[j] == ' ' || j == l) {
                   check[i] = 0; func[i] = 1;
                   arr[i][k] = '\0';
                   i++;
                   k = 0;
               }
               else {
                   arr[i][k] = str[j];
                   k++;
               }
           }

           for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
               for (j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {
                   if (check[i] == 0 && strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) == 0) {
                       check[j]++;
                       func[i]++;
                   }
               }
           }

           for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
               p *= factorial(func[i]);
           }

           n = factorial(m) / p;
           printf("%d/%d\n", 1, n);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Don't use comments for what could be described in the code directly**. This:

   ```
       int T;//number of test cases
       scanf("%d", &T);
       while (T--) {
   ```

   Should be really this:

   ```
       int number_of_test_cases;
       scanf("%d", &number_of_test_cases);
       while (number_of_test_cases--) {
   ```
3. **Avoid long functions for maintainability and readability.** You wrote one function for the factorial calculation; good. But now take a look
       at the `main()` function. Can you guess what the steps are in the `while`
       by looking at it? There's too much stuff going on in the `main()`.
       Isolate parts which do one thing into a function. For example this
       piece:

   ```
       int i, j, k, m, count = 0, l, p = 1, n;         
       l = strlen(str);

       for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {           
           if (str[i] == ' ') {
               count++;            
           }       
       }
   ```

   First of all I would write the variables on several lines to have it more readable:

   ```
       int i;
       int j;
       int k;
       int m;
       int count = 0;
       int l; 
       int p = 1;
       int n;
       l = strlen(str);

       for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
           if (str[i] == ' ') {
               count++;
           }
       }
   ```

   Then we realize that `j`, `k`, `m`, `p` and `n` are not even needed yet at this point, so we put 
    them after all this:

   ```
       int i;
       int count = 0;
       int l; 
       l = strlen(str);

       for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
           if (str[i] == ' ') {
               count++;
           }
       }

       int p = 1;
       int j;
       int k;
       int m;
       int n;
   ```

   Then another thing is `l` can be directly initialized with `strlen(str)`. Also I renamed 
   it everywhere in the program to `length` which  states more easily for a reader what it 
   does.

   This gives us this:

   ```
       int i;
       int count = 0;
       int length = strlen(str);

       for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           if (str[i] == ' ') {
               count++;
           }
       }
   ```

   Now we should make it a function so it looks like this:

   ```
       int length = strlen(str);
       int count = get_count_of_whitespace(&str, length);
   ```

   Proceed with the rest of the `main` function like that by refactoring it into 
   manageable chunks, and probably with that alone you will find some mistakes or improvements 
   for your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## Dangerous bug

Always take care to avoid buffer overruns such as this one:

> ```
> char str[20];
> scanf(" %[^\n]",str);
> ```

If you have a fixed-size buffer like that, you need to ensure that the input is limited to its length:

```
char str[20];
scanf(" %19[^\n]", str);
```

This is the kind of bug that leads to remote code execution or local privilege escalation in servers and setuid programs, respectively.  Get into the habit of coding defensively, so that you're not inviting attacks when your code is used in such a target system.

It's generally a good idea to examine the value returned by `scanf` - if it's not the number of variables you expected to assign, then reading has failed (perhaps you reached end-of-file?), and you can't expect to proceed normally.

## Prefer iteration to recursion

Some algorithms are naturally recursive (such as Quicksort).  Even implementations of those iterate as much as possible (typically in Quicksort, we recurse for the smaller partition, and iterate for the larger one).  For computation of factorial, there's really no need to recurse:

```
unsigned long factorial(unsigned n)
{
    unsigned long x = n;
    while (--n) {
        x *= n;
    }
    return x;
}
```

That said, computing factorial and then dividing by the appropriate amount to account for duplicates is prone to unnecessary overflow (consider a pathological case of *N* identical words, where *N*! is greater than `ULONG_MAX`).  It may be worth finding a safer algorithm for this.

Comment: Can you give me hint regarding any other algorithm...?